# Testthat does not see external csv data

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I'm writing test for my package and I want to use macro economical data rather than artificially randomized. The problem is that when I'm using `read.csv('my_file.csv')` and then running `test_that`, all tests using my data are ignored. For example

```
library('tseries')
library('testthat')
data<-read.csv('my_file.csv')
test_that('ADF test',{
    vec<-data[,2]
    expect_is(adf.test(vec),'htest')
})
```

After running 'testpackage' I get no information about failure or passing of my test. where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`testthat` only returns an error in console if the test didn't succeed:

```
library(testthat)
data<-iris
test_that('test1',{
  expect_is(data$Petal.Length,'numeric')
})

test_that('test2',{
  expect_is(data$Species,'numeric')
})
#> Error: Test failed: 'test2'
#> * <text>:8: data$Species inherits from `factor` not `numeric`.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can use `test_file` or `test_dir` to get the results:

```
res <- test_file('mytest.R',
                 reporter = "list",
                 env = test_env(),
                 start_end_reporter = TRUE,
                 load_helpers = TRUE,
                 wrap = TRUE)

√ |  OK F W S | Context
x |   1 1     | mytest
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mytest.R:8: failure: test2
data$Species inherits from `factor` not `numeric`.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

== Results =====================================================================
OK:       1
Failed:   1
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
Warning message:
`encoding` is deprecated; all files now assumed to be UTF-8
```

Comment: But running testthat from package level we get summary in which number of passed tests is included. 

E.g. OK: 3 
Failed : ..
warnings : ... 
Skipped : ...

Comment: The result is the same as in turning on testing at package level

Comment: In the example I just edited it shows one error and one passed : Isn't it what is expected?

Comment: @John, did this answer your question or I misunderstood your problem? Thanks for your feedback.